# Disable Buffering on Android VideoView / MediaController

Tags: android, caching, streaming, buffer, android-videoview

We are writing an Android App on the Samsung Galaxy Tab. We have an Endoscope (Medical Surgery Camera) as DV-input and we want to live-stream the DV Video to the Tablet. 
As a streaming server, we have the VLC player and a RTSP stream. The encoding works fine, and streaming over the network(rtsp) to another computer is good (< 1s). However, if we open the RTSP stream on the Galaxy Tab, there is a lag of 6-7s. 
I have tried to set down the bitrate encoding (even the lowest doesn't work, the streaming lag results the same). So I think there must be some kind of network caching or video caching on the Android itself.

I googled and didn't find a way to disable or even modify caching on the videoview / mediacontroller.
Does anyone have an idea how to tweak the Android Streaming View?

Edit: 
I figured out that it must be the internal buffer size that limits the video stream velocity. The LogCat tells me that AweSomePlayer is the Videoplayer in charge. So next question: How to change the awesomeplayer buffering size? I think it's written in cpp. How can I access this precompiled code via eclipse/java/android?